# Can not cancel a task after timeout period?

Tags: .net, timeout, task

In my MVC website project, I need to cancel the invoke code if it is pass the timeout, I wrote below code, it return the expected result correctly when not timeout, but when timeout, the code return to main thread but the child task still running (I checked task manager and see the IIS Worker thread use a lot of hardware), I do not know what is wrong with it.

```
    private static object GetCandidateOutput(MethodInfo mi, object o, string[][] input)
    {
        var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Run(() => mi.Invoke(o, input), cancellationToken.Token);
        if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
        {
            return task.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            cancellationToken.Cancel();
            throw new Exception("Timed out");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `cancellationToken.Cancel()` only sets the state of the token so that if someone checks it, he knows that the operation _should_ be cancelled. If the method referenced in `mi` is executing, `cancellationToken.Cancel()` has no effect as long as that method does not check `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested()` or calls `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. The call to `Cancel()` itself does not "terminate" any task or thread.

Comment: The invoke code is from another source and I can not edit it to throw the exception, how could I wait and handle for timeout in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, below is the working code:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(state =>
{
    var token = (CancellationToken)state;
    if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var invokeInput = new object[] { input };
        var output = mi.Invoke(o, invokeInput);
    }
}, cts.Token, cts.Token);


if (!newTask.Wait(timeout, cts.Token))
{
    cts.Cancel();
    throw new Exception("The operation has timed out.");
}
```